# Evaluating an expression assuming a value for a variable only in the local context

Tags: assumptions, assignment

Imagine we wish to evaluate some expression like `NIntegrate[x^2*q,{x,0,100}]` assuming some value for `q` like `q = x`.

How can we do this such that:

```
MakeLocalAssignmentOrAssumption[q = x, NIntegrate[x^2*q,{x,0,100}]]
Print[q]
```

Returns:

```
2.5*10^7
q
```

In other words, how can we assume that `q = x` ONLY in the context of evaluating the `NIntegrate` expression?

Comment: `NIntegrate` doesn't introduce a new context. Do you mean *scope* rather than *context*? (A context in _Mathematica_ is a name space).

Comment: @m_goldberg Perhaps yes - I just want Mathematica to assume that "q" has some value ONLY when evaluating the NIntegrate expression, and then not to have this value assigned to "q" anywhere else.

Comment: Use `Block` - that's exactly what it is for: `Block[{q = x}, NIntegrate[x^2*q, {x, 0, 100}]]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks!

Comment: `With[{q = x}, NIntegrate[x^2*q, {x, 0, 100}] ]` works also

Comment: @Nasser When should use With vs. Block?

Comment: This has summary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661393/mathematica-module-versus-with-or-block-guideline-rule-of-thumb-for-usage For me, I also think of `With` as making all the variables being `withed` as constants during the evaluation of the code inside `With`. So less chance of an error if you do not  need to modify the `withed` variable, such as `q` in this case. Mathematica in this case, changes `q` to `x` in all the expressions inside `With` right away, then evaluates the expression. You can't do `q=1` for example in this case, inside `With` later on, since `q` now is constant.

Comment: compare `x = 5; With[{q = x}, q = 1; q]` with `x = 5;
Block[{q = x}, q = 1; q]` in the first case, M gives error `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 5. >>` but not in the second case. This is because with `With` now `q` is constant `1`, and can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
x = 42.;
Block[{x, q}, With[{q = x}, NIntegrate[x^2*q, {x, 0, 100}]]]
```

> ```
> 2.5*10^7
> ```

q

> ```
> q
> ```

The `Block` construct declares `x` ansd `q` in the local scope. Also note, there is no need to use `Print` much in *Mathematica*, as the result of evaluating an expression or last expression in a compound expression ("statement") is always printed unless terminated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

While m_goldberg's answer is correct*, provides a proper explanation, and uses only documented behavior, there exists a cleaner syntax for the example given:

```
x = 42.;

With[{q := x}, NIntegrate[x^2*q, {x, 0, 100}]]
```

> ```
> 2.5*10^7
> ```

- The use of `:=` in `With` is an undocumented syntax but very useful: it prevents evaluation of `x` before it is substituted into the expression.
- We need not `Block` `x` as it is localized by `NIntegrate`.
- ***** It is unnecessary to `Block` `q` in any case as it is not evaluated by `With`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: use an immediate or delayed rule: `NIntegrate[x^2*q /. q -> x, {x, 0, 10}]`
or change the replacement `q->x` on the fly using a function `ff[x_]:= 1/(1-x)` 
`Table[ NIntegrate[x^2 q /. q:> ff[n x] ,{x,0,10}],{n,3}]`